# Creating a Stock Candle Graph in Chart JS

Tags: javascript, asp.net, excel, charts, chart.js

im building for my project a stock market website, im building right now the stock page that will show deatials about a stock including graph, im using for the graph an excel sheet that will be given a stock name and create a 1 year history data, im taking that data to create a graph but for some reason the graph is loaded and in the console there is no error and it says that it uploaded all the data points but the graph is still empty.
[this is what the console and graph is showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oxPAw.png)

would really like help im stuck :(

**this is the code to get the data from the excel (working)**

```
    public class StockData
    {
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public double OpenPrice { get; set; }
        public double ClosePrice { get; set; }
        public double LowPrice { get; set; }
        public double HighPrice { get; set; }
    }

    public class ExcelStockReader
    {
        private void WriteStockNameToExcel(string filePath, string stockName)
        {
            ExcelPackage.LicenseContext = LicenseContext.NonCommercial;
            using (var package = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(filePath)))
            {
                var worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[0];
                worksheet.Cells["A1"].Value = stockName;
                package.Save();
            }
        }

        public List<StockData> ReadExcelFile(string stockName)
        {
            var filePath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "App_Data\\Stock_Chart.xlsm";
            WriteStockNameToExcel(filePath, "MSFT");

            var stockDataList = new List<StockData>();
            bool isFirstRow = true;

            using (var stream = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                using (var reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateReader(stream))
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        if (isFirstRow)
                        { isFirstRow = false; }
                        else
                        {
                            var stockData = new StockData
                            {
                                Date = DateTime.FromOADate(reader.GetDouble(1)),
                                OpenPrice = reader.GetDouble(2),
                                ClosePrice = reader.GetDouble(3),
                                LowPrice = reader.GetDouble(4),
                                HighPrice = reader.GetDouble(5)
                            };
                            stockDataList.Add(stockData);
```

**this is ASPX code**

```
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.7.1/chart.js" integrity="sha512-Lii3WMtgA0C0qmmkdCpsG0Gjr6M0ajRyQRQSbTF6BsrVh/nhZdHpVZ76iMIPvQwz1eoXC3DmAg9K51qT5/dEVg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>    <!-- Luxon Script -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/moment"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-adapter-moment"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/chartjs-chart-financial"></script>
    <script src="StockData_Page.js"></script>
            <canvas id="stockChartCanvas"></canvas>
```

**and this the js function to use all of this**

```
function createChart(chartData) {
    var formattedData = chartData.map((data, index) => {
        var formatted = {
            x: data.t,
            o: parseFloat(data.o),
            h: parseFloat(data.h),
            l: parseFloat(data.l),
            c: parseFloat(data.c)
        };

        console.log(`Data point ${index}:`, formatted);
        return formatted;
    });

    var ctx = document.getElementById('stockChartCanvas').getContext('2d');

    var stockChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'candlestick',
        data: {
            datasets: [{
                label: 'Stock Data',
                data: formattedData
            }]
        },
        options: {
            scales: {
                x: {
                    type: 'time',
                    time: {
                        unit: 'day'
                    }
                },
                y: {
                    beginAtZero: false
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Your image doesn't show the console, only the empty chart. However, it would be very helpful if you added a `console.log(chartData)` as the first line in `createChart` and include in your post the output of that log, *as plain text* not as an image (hopefully a reasonable number of points too, not in the  hundreds).